# Looking for best practices when updating a tableview by monitoring for changes in DB

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore

I'm somewhat new to this and this is my first question on stackoverflow. Thanks in advance for your help and bear with me if my formatting sucks

I've got multiple views within my app (all displaying data using tableview subviews) that need to update automatically when the data changes on the database (Firestore), i.e. another user updates the data.

I've found a way to do this which is working well, but I want to ask the community if there's a better way.

Currently, I am creating a Timer object with a timeInterval of 2. On the interval, the timer queries the database and checks a stored data sample against updated data. If the two values vary, I run viewDidLoad which contains my original query, tableView.reloadData(), etc..

Any suggestions or affirmations would be very useful.

```
var timer = Timer()
var oldChallengesArray = [String]()
var newChallengesArray = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    //set tableview delegate
    mainTableView.delegate = self
    mainTableView.dataSource = self
    
    //set challengesmodel delegate
    challengesModel.delegate = self
    
    //get challenges
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.challengesModel.getChallenges(accepted: true, challengeDenied: false, incomingChallenges: false, matchOver: false)
        self.mainTableView.reloadData()
    }
            
    scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval()
}

func scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(){
    // Scheduling timer to Call the function "updateCounting" with the interval of 1 seconds
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateTableView), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func updateTableView(){
    ChallengeService.getAllUserChallengeIDs(accepted: true, challengeDenied: false, matchOver: false) { (array) in
        
        if array.isEmpty {
            return
        } else {
            self.newChallengesArray = array
            if self.oldChallengesArray != self.newChallengesArray {
                self.oldChallengesArray = self.newChallengesArray
                self.newChallengesArray.removeAll()
                self.viewDidLoad()
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore is a "realtime database", that means that the database warns you when changes happen to the data. To achieve that the app needs to subscribe to relevant changes in the db. The sample code below can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#swift):

```
db.collection("cities").document("SF")
    .addSnapshotListener { documentSnapshot, error in
      guard let document = documentSnapshot else {
        print("Error fetching document: \(error!)")
        return
      }
      guard let data = document.data() else {
        print("Document data was empty.")
        return
      }
      print("Current data: \(data)")
    }
```

Also, I would like to point out that calling viewDidLoad is incorrect, you should never call viewDidLoad yourself, create an func to update the data. Something like this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.mainTableView.reloadData()
    }
```